# Apps stuck in pending update status?

Tags: itunes, applications, software-update

I used my MacBook Pro and iTunes to download updates for my mobile apps. I then sync'd and the apps were updated. I verified they were updated through the device's *Settings* app.

However, when I visit *App Store* on the mobile device, the apps are shown as *Pending Updates* status even though they are up to date (see image below). I've opened the app several times, and it has not cleared the incorrect status problem. I've rebooted the device several times, and it has not cleared the incorrect status problem.

I also cycled *App Store* in the *Notifications* center with no joy. The *App Store* app still claims the apps are pending updates.

How do I clear the *Pending Updates* status?

---

The MacBook Pro is running OS X 10.8.5 (fully patched). The iPad is running iOS 8.2 (fully patched).

---

[image]

Comment: did you cycle iPad off/on ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 - Yes, two or three times now. Man I *wish* Apple would test their software before releasing it on the world....

Comment: @jww one person having an issue does not mean it is a widespread or easily-caught bug. At any rate, when you say you rebooted, did you hold Home + Sleep until the Apple logo appears? This often resolves issues that aren't fixed by a simple power cycle. I have had this issue in the past, though it was unrelated to a sync and each time eventually resolved itself after a couple of days.

Comment: @tubedogg - thanks, I'll give it a couple of days and try again. If you had the problem and I have the problem, its seems to indicate its more than a one-off. I stand by my statements that Apple needs to test their crap before releasing it. As a consumer who pays good money for this stuff, I consider companies like Apple stealing from me when they give me defective goods. If they want me to debug their broken stuff in the field, then they need to provide the equipment.

Comment: @jww I think you might be overreacting just a tiny bit. Software has bugs. Not all of them are able to be found before millions of people start using the software. There may be something particular in your configuration, or the exact order of the steps you took, or the combination apps listed in particular, that caused this to occur, and no amount of testing or planning would have caused Apple to stumble onto the exact circumstances that made it happen. (In addition to the fact that this bug is hardly a critical one by any means. It is annoying, yes, but it did not cause you to lose data,

Comment: brick your device, cause irreparable harm to anything, or prevent you from using all of the functions of your device.)

Answer (score 2):

iOS 9.2

**Option 1:**
Try going to Settings -> iTunes & App Store -> and under Automatic Downloads, toggling the Updates switch next to the App Store logo. Now keep the Settings app open, ensure the App Store is closed, and reopen it. If this works, switch back to the Settings app, and toggle Automatic Downloads for Updates back on; if this doesn't work, still switch back to the Settings app, tap your Apple ID, and sign out of the App Store. Restart your iOS device (for safe measure), then sign back into the App Store with your Apple ID.

**Option 2:**
Backup your iOS device. Delete the apps pending updates, and reinstall them. This will force the apps to be flushed from the App Store as they no longer exist on your iOS device, but you'll also remove any data contained within the apps. You can easily reinstall the apps by opening the App Store, going to Updates -> Purchased, and downloading the apps from there.

Comment: Be careful before deleting apps! You can lose data.