# iOS: Pressing Update opens the app

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ios

iPhone 4.

When I'm in the app store, and I want to update an app, I go to the updates tab and I click update. It proceeds to open the app without updating it.

I have tried hard shutdown, soft shutdown, and deleting the app.

Any help?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177500/apps-stuck-in-pending-update-status

Comment: your comment in that question is what i have done already (hard shutdown). I may call it differently from what you call it. @tubedogg